# How do I coerce Ruby's BigDecimal::round to give me more precision?

Tags: ruby, rounding, precision, bigdecimal

I'm working on [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/archives)'s problem 26, which involves finding repetitions in the decimal place when I do division such as 1/6, 1/7, 1/8 etc.

I'm having a hard time getting `BigDecimal` to give enough precision to find long patterns of repetition. I'd like to force precision of an arbitrary number of places; however, using `round(x)` still caps at around 18 places.

```
puts (BigDecimal("1.0") / 7).round(25).to_s("F")
puts (BigDecimal("1.0") / 7).round(25).precs
```

yields `0.142857142857142857` and `[18, 27]`, respectively. What is the reason it is limited to 18 decimal places? Is there a way to get meaningful decimals past that, or even past the system limit of 27?

Comment: I think this is the wrong approach.  Think about how you could generate those digits one-by-one using only integer arithmetic.

Comment: It did occur to me that you could iterate through 1/n, 10/n, 100/n taking only the first decimal place each time. But I was hoping to simply be able to do the division followed by perhaps a regex search for repetition.